# Logic inside Django serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a Django serializer implementation that has a field which contains a list as part of a JWT authentication process. For example:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        field = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I then have some logic in my user model

```
class MyUser(PermissionMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
   permissions = ['OK', 'NOT_OK']
```

I can access my users from the following logic inside my serializer

```
self.context['request'].user.permissions
```

I would now like to only share parts `a` and `b` of `field` if the user is not permitted to access `c`. In other words I want to do something roughly equivalent to

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        if 'OK' in self.context['request'].user.permissions:
           field = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        else:
           field = ['a', 'b']
```

However, the Meta class does not have self attached. What is the best design pattern to achieve what I want? Is the serializer the best place to house this logic?

Comment: You may create two serializers, one with fields (a ,b and c), and the other with fields (a and b) only. and choose which to use in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to alter the serialization or deserialization behavior of a serializer class, you can do so by overriding the .to_representation() or .to_internal_value() methods.

Some reasons this might be useful include...

- Adding new behavior for new serializer base classes.
- Modifying the behavior slightly for an existing class.
- Improving serialization performance for a frequently accessed API endpoint that returns lots of data.

The signatures for these methods are as follows:
.to_representation(self, instance)

Takes the object instance that requires serialization, and should return a primitive representation. Typically this means returning a structure of built-in Python datatypes. The exact types that can be handled will depend on the render classes you have configured for your API.

May be overridden in order to modify the representation style. For example:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    ret['username'] = ret['username'].lower()
    return ret
```

ref: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior